# IActionResult pass object and message in Ok

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

In .NET 6 API controller, I'm returning data with Ok `IActionResult`, below is my code, there I want to pass a string message along with `return Ok(employee);`

Is it possible if so, please suggest how to do it.

```cs
[Route("{Id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Employee))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(int Id)
{
    var listEmployees = new List<Employee>()
                    {
                        new Employee(){ Id = 1001, Name = "Anurag", Age = 28, City = "Mumbai", Gender = "Male", Department = "IT" },
                        new Employee(){ Id = 1002, Name = "Pranaya", Age = 28, City = "Delhi", Gender = "Male", Department = "IT" },
                        new Employee(){ Id = 1003, Name = "Priyanka", Age = 27, City = "BBSR", Gender = "Female", Department = "HR"},
                    };
    var employee = listEmployees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.Id == Id);
    if (employee != null)
    {
        **return Ok(employee);**
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately don't think that is possible to do. The workaround could be that you add an extra field to the Employee object such as a string of description that gets returned as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return the message with the data as well, I would suggest creating a model class that allows returning multiple values.

For example, an `ApiResponse` class that support generic type.

```cs
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public T Data { get; set; } 
}
```

And your controller action to return the value of `ApiResponse<Employee>` type for the status 200 scenario as below:

```cs
[Route("{Id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(ApiResponse<Employee>))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(int Id)
{
    var listEmployees = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee(){ Id = 1001, Name = "Anurag", Age = 28, City = "Mumbai", Gender = "Male", Department = "IT" },
        new Employee(){ Id = 1002, Name = "Pranaya", Age = 28, City = "Delhi", Gender = "Male", Department = "IT" },
        new Employee(){ Id = 1003, Name = "Priyanka", Age = 27, City = "BBSR", Gender = "Female", Department = "HR"},
    };
    var employee = listEmployees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.Id == Id);
    if (employee != null)
    {
        return Ok(new ApiResponse<Employee>
        {
            Message = "Assign your message here",
            Data = employee
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```